# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (The wait operation timed out) when debugging only

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

The code code works with smaller queries even on debug. I tried some larger queries, and it works with the server/live version but not when debugging with visual studio. I tried the same query with SSMS and it worked fine, pretty quick too.

The query is via a stored procedure:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING))
{
   partialReport = conn.Query<MonthlyReporting>("PartialReport", new { ClassLevel = (int)instruct, StartDate = startDate, EndDate = endDate, IncludeMarried = includeMarried }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();

   // program does stuff here
}
```

The full exception details is:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
> HResult=0x80131904
> Message=Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
>
> Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
>
> StackTrace:
> Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace
>
> Inner Exception 1:
> Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out

The code is identical between the Server and Debug versions of the code, and the debug database is the same as the server/live database (although a few days older). Likewise, the CONNECTION_STRING is different, pointing to the debug/live database respectively.

Once again, this DOES work even when debugging with smaller queries.

Comment: This is a client-side timeout.  Increase the SqlConnection.CommandTimeout and/or troubleshoot query execution on the server.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Most likely you are suffering from a slow query on that server. Please share the query plans from the two servers via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. Please also [edit] and add the stored procedure, table and index definitions to your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by doing essentially nothing. I encountered the same problem at a different part of the code, but I pressed continue after the error. I refreshed the page a few times to see if there was any consistency with the time it took for the error to appear. I was doing this because I tried changing the connection timeout with no success, (the refreshing was done with my original connection timeout settings). after refreshing a few times, the problem just went away (at both locations in the code).
I think the problem is caused when I copy the database from the live version/server to the local debug version.

Update: I think the issue was that my test environment didn't have enough RAM, causing caching issues.

Comment: It is recommended to increase the duration of `SqlConnection.CommandTimeout`.

Comment: I changed the Connect Timeout property in my connection string from 30 to 120, without success. I am still getting the error. After brute force refreshing half a dozen times, to problem goes away. Still not sure about the root cause.

Comment: As mentioned above there are 2 distinct timeouts: 
- the CommandTimeout is needed when the query is very slow. it defaults to 30 seconds. 
- the ConnectionTimeout is used only to establish the initial database Connection.